# SharePoint Apps, IA and Search

Tags: search, sharepoint-addin, information-architecture

This is a two part question that I was going to split into two seller are posts, but think the wider "discussion" fits being in one post.

I am looking to write some SharePoint Apps and two questions I have are:

1) How does the model integrate with an organisations Global Information Architecture.
2) How is content stored in Apps indexed by search?

Basically are things like managed Metadata, Enterprise Content Types (such as those in the content type hub), etc, brought into my app to be used for tagging content stored in the app?

Also, how is that content then indexed and aggregated out of my app for inclusion in global content find ability?

So far I have seen very little discussion on this and I fear that moving content out of SharePoint sites into App Webs may lead to a confusion on corporate taxonomy and content find ability.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I was discussing this with someone at spevo and the only way I can think of indexing the contents/data within an app is to configure it was a result source using an app level external content type backed by BCS.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I was also talking to a couple of people at SpEvo and got the same response.  I'm concerned about "loosing information" in Apps and would like to get the views of IA and governance gurus on this topic.